# Visual Studio debugger hangs, unable to detach from w3wp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, freeze

I've inherited a sprawling, aged codebase and I'm experiencing a behavior I've never seen. Sometimes, when debugging, if I'm browsing through objects or collections in the Watch window, the debugger will hang. It's consistently the same place, same object type, etc. After about 15 seconds, Visual Studio comes back to me, but the debugger no longer works and will not until I restart the debugging session. When I do stop the debugger, I get:

```
"Cannot detach from one or more processes: [6088] w3wp.exe: 
All outstanding func-evals have not completed, detaching is not allowed 
at this time."
```

And I have to terminate the process to continue.

I've read enough about the problem to theorize it has something to do with threading, but that's a few feet over my head. I would like to know if anyone has encountered this, how to figure out the specific issue, and most of all how to prevent it. I'd even take a solution that blocks the debugger from going down that branch just to keep from breaking my debugger, as it is quite annoying.

Any and all advice is welcome. I cannot share much of any code, due to job requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be caused by an infinite recursion/loop in the code you are trying to call but you might be able to bypass the issue by using some of the "Debugger..." attributes in the namespace here: [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t15zda.aspx) Which tell the debugger not to step into etc.